# convert datatable to listview vb.net

Tags: java, asp.net, vb.net

i made a datatable, but want to change it to list view.

using vb.net

mycode:

```
Dim table As New DataTable

    ' columns in the DataTable.
    table.Columns.Add("Monday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Tuesday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Wednesday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Thursday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    table.Columns.Add("Friday", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
    '  rows with those columns filled in the DataTable.
    table.Rows.Add(1, 2005, 2000, 4000, 34)
    table.Rows.Add(2, 3024, 2343, 2342, 12)
    table.Rows.Add(3, 2320, 9890, 1278, 2)
    table.Rows.Add(4, 3420, 1234, 4321, 89)
    table.Rows.Add(5, 3240, 6600, 1100, 56)
    table.Rows.Add(6, 4320, 1100, 3243, 23)
    table.Rows.Add(7, 4540, 7645, 4324, 56)
    table.Rows.Add(8, 4540, 4321, 8905, 43)
    table.Rows.Add(9, 3420, 7654, 6780, 23)
    table.Rows.Add(10, 4530, 6734, 9856, 21)
    table.Rows.Add(11, 3240, 1278, 4327, 12)
```

how do i create a datatable with a list view, with the colume, Mon, tues etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link below might help you

[Fill a ListView with any Dataset](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_listview_sort_dataset.html)

Comment: how would i convert this into list view in aspx page